# Can not show view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show my custom view when there is no network connection.

Something like this:

[image]

I have a `ViewController` inside a `NavigationController`

in `AppDelegate` I write like this:

```
var statusView: NetworkStatusView?
...

func showNetworkStatusView() {
        if statusView == nil {
            statusView = NetworkStatusView()
            if let statusView = statusView {
                let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                statusView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 60)
                statusView.hidden = false
                if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController {
                    rootViewController.view.addSubview(statusView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and In my ViewController, I call like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.showNetworkStatusView()
```

But it doesn't show my custom view. I've also try `view.addSubView(statusView)` in my `ViewController`, but doesn't work also.  I make sure that the function is called, because I debugged.

Here is my `NetworkStatusView`:

```
import UIKit

class NetworkStatusView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initSubviews()
    }

    func initSubviews() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "NetworkStatusView", bundle: nil)
        nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
        contentView.frame = bounds
        addSubview(contentView)
    }

}
```

Comment: showNetworkStatusView() is called on main thread ?

Comment: I have tried putting it on main thread, but not work.

Comment: can you show NetworkStatusView's init method implementation ? Do you load your xib ?

Comment: @azimov NetworkStatusView is a xib file. I have put my code about NetworkStatusView. Please check again. Thanks :)

Comment: You are doing it wrong. I would do it this way, move initSubviews() in init(frame: CGRect), and in the client class call NetworkStatusView(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 60))

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: initSubviews() in your case is not called, because initWithCoder is itself called when a xib/storyboard (in UIView case) is deserialized (loaded), but nothing triggers initWithCoder call